# Getting user's current location before doing next event in single method?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

My requirement here is to get the user's current location and pass to map.google.com. And the most imp condition is : these two events must happen in a single method.

And my problem here is , I have to pass the user's location, but it is only obtained through the delegate of CLlocationManager.Basically i need user's location before calling for map.google.com.

(imp: i can't call for CLLocationManager in my viewwillappear or anywhere else in the code)

So, can we solve this issue using block handler? 
Any help,links would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your restrictions - you say that the two lines must happen in a single method, but then you talk about using a block - which is just another method of asynchronous execution. Obtaining a location takes time. You either need to start collecting location data earlier and only enable the button or whatever triggers the action once you have a location or you need to accept some (potential) delay between triggering the action and the map being displayed.

Comment: My requirement is: when user taps on the text(location name) in the view , my app should show the path to that location in the maps.google.com. I will have destination coordinates already but won't have the user's current location. (imp note: since this view is dynamic i cannot  call for the CLLocationManager  each time my view loads. It should happen only when the user click that particular location name)

Comment: I don't understand why you can't start tracking location in your AppDelegate - then you will probably already have the users location ready to go. Acquiring a location can take between 30 seconds and many minutes if there is poor GPS coverage.

Answer (score 0):

One of several solutions could be to use a third party library. Here one I used for geolocation, very light, simple, and blockbased : https://gist.github.com/steakknife/6972228

### EDIT :

Here's an example to easily find the current location in one-line way using the synchronous method `currentLocationByWaitingUpToMilliseconds:success:` of the little library quoted above :

```
CLLocation *location = [LocationManager currentLocationByWaitingUpToMilliseconds:1000 success:nil];
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.